# Silverlight CSharpCodeDomClientCodeGenerator fatal exception

Tags: silverlight, exception, fatal-error

Receiving this error when trying to build a Silverlight 4 project.

> The code generator
>   'Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.CSharpCodeDomClientCodeGenerator'
>   encountered a fatal exception and could not generate code for project
>   'TheProject.csproj': Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the real problems were hidden by DataAnnotations, as described here:
http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2012/01/23/csharpcodedomclientcodegenerator-encountered-a-fatal-exception.aspx

comment them all out and the real error appeared for me.